# How to tell if ssh/telnet session is ended with expect (tcl)

Tags: ssh, tcl, expect

I have inherited an expect script that logins in to a remote server and may need to exit after either `n` *or* `n-1` commands. Unfortunately I need to be able to know if the server logged me off. How can control for this? My expect code that sends the commands looks like:

```
for { set i $index } { $i < $n } { incr i } {
    expect -re $prompt
    send "[lindex $array $i]\r"
}
```

If I just hammer the remote server with `n` commands when `n-1` commands are called for I get an error like:

```
send: spawn id exp6 not open
    while executing
"send "[lindex $array $i]\r""
    ("for" body line 7)
```

where `$array` is the list of n commands. I guess that exp6 means "6th expression", which in this case would be `n`? I'm trying to find documentation for the error but not finding much, any suggestions are welcome.

---

EDIT

Another hacky way to solve my particular problem would be to remove repeated commands from the tail end of the array/list, but only from the tail of the list

```
[foo bar foo foo bar bar]
```

In other words, delete `array[-1]` iff `array[-1] == array[-2]`. I still need `array[1]`.

Comment: `exp6` is the `$spawn_id`. you can verify this with `expect -c 'spawn -noe sleep 1; puts $spawn_id'`.

Comment: why/when the server would log you off before you finish all the commands?

Comment: A stochastic environment.

Comment: And what is "spawn_id"? https://core.tcl-lang.org/expect/FAQ.html is 404.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `eof` pattern. Unested

```
foreach cmd $array {
    expect {
        eof {
            puts "spawned process has closed"
            break
        }
        -re $prompt
    }
    send "$cmd\r"
}
```